# UIView's center of rotation

Tags: iphone

Is there a counterpart to the CALayer's anchorPoint for a UIView?

I'd like to rotate my UIView around a point other than the center of the bounds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To follow up on what Daniel said, according to the [UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform):

> The origin of the transform is the
>   value of the center property, or the
>   layer’s anchorPoint property if it was
>   changed. (Use the layer property to
>   get the underlying Core Animation
>   layer object.)

Therefore, if you set the anchorPoint in the UIView's layer, transforms applied directly to the UIView will occur about that point.

Answer (score 0):

No, if u want to do it U'll have to use the layer I'm pretty sure